# java spark framework can not set or read cookie

Tags: java, cookies, spark-java

I am new to the spark framework. I got problem when i was trying to set cookie to response or read cookie from request.

The route:

```
post("/test/set/cookie", TestController.setCookie);
        get("/test/get/cookie", TestController.getCookie);
        post("/test/remove/cookie", TestController.removeCookie);
```

controller:

```
public static Route setCookie = (Request request, Response response) -> {
        System.out.println("set");
        String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        response.cookie("test1", id, 3600, false, true);
        return "done";
    };

    public static Route getCookie = (Request request, Response response) -> {
        System.out.println("get");
        String cookie = request.cookie("test1");
        System.out.println(cookie);
        return "done";
    };

    public static Route removeCookie = (Request request, Response response) -> {
        System.out.println("remove");
        response.removeCookie("test1");
        return "done";
    };
```

[Postman set cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djVIz.png)

[Postman get cookie faile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMPYK.png)

what i am missing?

Comment: Please don't use links to show the error. Write it in words what error you are getting.

Comment: sorry, when i using postman to post /test/set/cookie,  it did work, the cookie "test1" had been set.  but when i get /test/get/cookie,  the request.cookie("test1") return null.

Comment: spark version 2.5.4

Comment: `<dependency>
            <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.4</version>
        </dependency>`

Answer (score 4):

I solved it finally---

`response.cookie("/", "test", "value", 3600, false, true);`

just need to add the path `"/"` to the cookie.